# Manageiq not access to Hawkular in Centos 7 VMWare

Tags: vmware-workstation, hawkular, manageiq

My development environment is CentOS 7 in vmware workstation 11 and manageiq docker container (manageiq/manageiq:euwe-2) on eclipse docker perspective. The manageiq appplication (https://127.0.0.1:8443) is executed well. But connecting hawkular is failed. Below is my hawkular execution command

```
<HAWKULAR_HOME>./standalone.sh -Dhawkular.rest.user=jhwang –Dhawkular.rest.password=password -Dhawkular.agent.enabled=true -b 192.168.200.51
```

In manageiq web console I type in the IP address on hawkular hostname but connection failes. Here is the image of manageiq:

[image]

Outside of VMWare workstation, the above process works well. ManageIQ is making the connection with the Hawkular with Hawkular binding IP address. But in vmware, no access. I am afraid I am using wrong Hawkular binding address. I attach the output of `ifconfig` command.

```
$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::42:8fff:fe28:6f2d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:8f:28:6f:2d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1283  bytes 342465 (334.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1344  bytes 157135 (153.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.200.51  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.200.255
        inet6 fe80::c494:6514:b641:e046  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:57:00:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10875  bytes 7648436 (7.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7465  bytes 1019458 (995.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 48647  bytes 14786880 (14.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 48647  bytes 14786880 (14.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethcf88378: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::c000:d9ff:fe82:e915  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c2:00:d9:82:e9:15  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1283  bytes 360427 (351.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1352  bytes 157783 (154.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:ce:2f:27  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And these are logs

```
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:01.546217 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 862] [client 172.17.0.1:58384] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0, referer: https://127.0.0.1:8443/
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:01.546274 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 862] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:3008 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:01.546280 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 862] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:01.546281 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 862] [client 172.17.0.1:58384] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0, referer: https://127.0.0.1:8443/
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:01.546346 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 862] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:3009 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:01.546352 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 862] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:01.546353 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 862] [client 172.17.0.1:58384] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0, referer: https://127.0.0.1:8443/
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.874238 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 864] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: WS: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:5001 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.875769 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 864] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.876936 2017] [proxy_wstunnel:error] [pid 864] [client 172.17.0.1:58492] AH02452: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.877157 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 864] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: WS: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:5002 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.877170 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 864] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.877173 2017] [proxy_wstunnel:error] [pid 864] [client 172.17.0.1:58492] AH02452: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.877542 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 864] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: WS: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:5003 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.877552 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 864] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.877554 2017] [proxy_wstunnel:error] [pid 864] [client 172.17.0.1:58492] AH02452: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.877717 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 864] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: WS: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:5004 (0.0.0.0) failed
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.877724 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 864] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (0.0.0.0) for 60s
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.877726 2017] [proxy_wstunnel:error] [pid 864] [client 172.17.0.1:58492] AH02452: failed to make connection to backend: 0.0.0.0
[Sun Apr 23 01:08:17.877799 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 864] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: WS: attempt to connect to 0.0.0.0:5005 (0.0.0.0) failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This disconnection is due to `"iptables that was blocking the loopback port"`.
So the one command line solved my issue.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Changing ip address of docker0(172.17.0.1/16) to the ip address of centos 7 ens33(192.168.200.51/24) bring the internet shut down. CentOS 7 of vmware workstation can not be connected to Internet. Pls, give me any help to bind some ports of the host on the container. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This answer contained a great deal of material that should have been in the question. If you would like to move it there now, to add context to the original question, you can find it in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43705620/revisions). When presenting new additional information to support a question, please _always_ add it to the question post itself.